# Producer and Consumer in java use notify() and wait() run 4 threads

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, producer-consumer

Recently ,I learned about the notify and wait in Java Thread Communication, and I tried to write the classical problem of Consumer&Producer, in my code ,I actually have 4 threads ,2 are consumers and the other 2 are producers.

```
package producer_consumer;

class Shared {
    private volatile boolean writable = true;
    public Character character = 'A';
    public synchronized void produceChar(Character c) {

        while (!writable) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        writable = false;

        character = c;
        notify();

    }

    public synchronized void consumerChar() {

        while (writable) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        writable = true;
        notify();
    }

}
public class PC {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Shared shared = new Shared();

        class Producer extends Thread {
            @Override
            public synchronized void run() {
                for(Character character = 'A';character<'Z';character++) {
                    shared.produceChar(character);
                    System.out.println(shared.character + " is produced");
                }
            }
        }


        class Consumer extends Thread {
            @Override
            public synchronized void run() {
                do {
                    shared.consumerChar();
                    System.out.println(shared.character + " is consumed");
                }while (shared.character!='Z');
            }
        }

        Producer p1 = new Producer();
        Producer p2 = new Producer();

        Consumer c1 = new Consumer();
        Consumer c2 = new Consumer();

        p1.start();
        p2.start();
        c1.start();
        c2.start();

    }
}
```

however,when I tried to run the code , it didn't work out. I supposed it will print the letters  from A to Z ,but it always get stucked. I know there must be something wrong ,but I can't figure it out by myself. Actually ,I don't konw what's wrong with it . So ,anyone will help me ? Thank you!

Comment: sometimes it does work fine，but sometimes does't.  it wii stop after print several characters

Comment: Don't synchronize your run method. It only gets called once.

Comment: You should use `notifyAll()` instead of `notify()` since there are more than 1 consumer and 1 producer threads

Answer (score 4):

When your code calls notify, that tells the scheduler to pick one thread from the waitset for the lock you called notify on, and wake it up. The scheduler has no knowledge of what specific condition the threads are waiting for and there's no telling which one it will pick.

When you have multiple threads, some of which are waiting on different conditions (here the conditions are writable and not writable), then it's possible for a thread to be notified for a condition that it is not interested in. The notified thread goes back to waiting once it figures out the condition it's looking for isn't present, and no other thread receives it. That means nobody makes progress as a result of that event.

Example:

1) First producer executes, writable is true, letting it skip waiting, write s char, call notify (nobody's listening), and flip the writable flag to false.

2) Context switch to second producer, it finds writable is false so it waits.

3) At this point the scheduler could run a consumer if one is through starting, or it could switch back to the first producer. 
Say it picks the producer. The first producer sees writable is still false, so it waits.

4) the first consumer runs. Writable is false so no waiting; it flips the writable flag to true and calls notify.

5) now 2 producers are waiting, the notify will wake one of them, the other is still waiting.

6) the first consumer can be picked to run again, writable is true so it waits. Now there is one producer waiting and  one consumer waiting.

7) At this point the scheduler can pick either the remaining active consumer or the remaining active producer. If it picks the producer then the producer can act, then call notify. Either waiting thread could be notified. Only one can act on the notification.

One solution is to use notifyAll. That wakes up all the threads in the waitset, so if any of them are interested then they'll be notified. This is not a perfect solution for all cases; in a program with a lot of threads it can mean a lot of unproductive context switching and state transitions for most of the threads, who end up eventually going back to their wait state without having made any headway. For a small program that's not an issue, of course.

A real world solution without the downside of notifyAll is to use ReentrantLock, which allows separate conditions. That way threads wait on specific Condition objects, with the result that the notification goes only to a thread that is waiting for that specific condition.

The api doc for Condition has an example of a bounded fixed size queue that shows threads waiting on different condition objects depending on if they are producers or consumers.  The conditions are not empty and not full. Threads inserting things to a full queue have to wait for the not full condition. Threads trying to take items out of an empty queue wait for the not empty condition.

Btw putting synchronized on the run method doesn't accomplish anything. Each thread is acquiring a lock on itself for the life of the thread. Locks must be shared in order to be useful. All it does is make it difficult for a thread joining on any of these to enter the waiting state.

Comment: @David: yes. I should add more detail here